# add an increment to a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

How can we add an increment (number) for a filename it its already existed and it should not repeat on a filename so that we can avoid duplicate filenames or more. context.data.filename is the filename we are going to insert to the db and the variable we wanted to add an increment. Or would also be good if we add the date and number?

```
const checkFilenameIFExists = () => async (context) => {
const record = await context.app.service('people')
  .Model.findByPk(context.data.peopleId);
if (!record) {
  throw new errors.BadRequest('People record does not exist.');
}
    
// check if filename already exists
const file = await context.service.Model.findOne({
  where: { peopleId: record.id, filename: context.data.filename },
});
    
if (file) {
  //this is where I want to add an increment
  context.data.filename
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably `context.data.filename` is a string, so it's tricky (though not impossible of course) to 'increment'. Sounds like what you want is to always create a new filename, but potentially in future locate multiple filenames that are updates of the same data?

To ensure it is unique, the easiest thing to use would be a timestamp. Something like this:

```js
if (file) {
  let prefix = Date.now().toString();
  context.data.filename = prefix + context.data.filename
}
```

Or if you want it at the end:

```js
if (file) {
  let prefix = "." + Date.now().toString();
  context.data.filename += prefix
}
```

Comment: but potentially in future locate multiple filenames that are updates of the same data? what do you mean by this question sir ?

Comment: yeah your right on this one sir "Sounds like what you want is to always create a new filename, "

Comment: whoops I wrote 'number' but meant 'string' - I will edit that. Looks like this answered your question, what I meant by my question is "do you want to be able to find filenames that are all updates of the same original file?"

Comment: can we increment a number or an ordinal suffix Sir rather than a timestamp ?

Comment: can we increment a number sir instead of using timestamp ?

Comment: You can only 'increment' if your filename is a number. But then how will you know it's a unique name?

Comment: this is my problem Sir

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63206044/making-a-record-unique-by-incrementing-a-number-in-javascript/63206223#63206223

Comment: by adding an ordinal suffix to the filename Sir

Comment: I have a query that check if the record exist if it exists maybe then we can add a number or an ordinal suffix