# making a record unique by incrementing a number in javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I wanted to increment a number to a filename if the filename already exists in the database (based on the records too). for example if I add file with filename DOC it will check if DOC exist since DOC exist on the example below and the latest increment is 1 (DOC-1) then the filename would be DOC-2. If I add DOC again and the latest increment is 2 so the new filename would be DOC-3.so on and so forth. Any idea guys ? thank you.

Sounds like what I want is to always create a new filename (by adding an increment or number to a filename) , also to potentially in .future locate multiple filenames that are updates of the same data.

#Code for searching if record exists(works fine)

```
const file = await context.service.Model.findOne({
    where: { employeeId: record.id, filename: data.filename },
    paranoid: false,
  });
```

#code that changes the filename (current implementation usi

```
     if (file) {
//this is where we add number to filename
        filename = getNumberedFileName(data.filename)
      }
```

#code to add number to filename

```
function getNumberedFileName(fileN) {
    //These are value initializations to cope with the situation when the file does not have a .
    var fileName = fileN;
    var fileExtension = "";
    var lastDotIndex = fileN.lastIndexOf(".");
    if ((lastDotIndex > 0) && (lastDotIndex < fileN.length - 1)) { //We are not interested in file extensions for files without an extension hidden in UNIX systems, like .gitignore and we are not interested in file extensions if the file ends with a dot
        fileName = fileN.substring(0, lastDotIndex);
        fileExtension = "." + fileN.substring(lastDotIndex + 1);
    }
    var lastDashIndex = fileName.lastIndexOf("-");
    if ((lastDashIndex > 0) && (lastDashIndex < fileName.length - 1)) {
        var lastPart = fileName.substring(lastDashIndex + 1);
        if (!isNaN(lastPart)) {
            var index = parseInt(lastPart) + 1;
            return fileName.substring(0, lastDashIndex) + "-" + index + fileExtension;
        }
    }
    return fileName + "-1" + fileExtension;
}
```

[image: DATABASE RECORD]

Comment: I have answered this question already with my function `makeUnique()` to [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63204745/javascript-how-would-you-make-a-record-unique-by-adding-a-number/63205026#63205026) of yours.

Comment: do I need to map the result of the file query and map it to makeUnique ?

Comment: You can call `makeUnique(filename)` like a normal function. It *is* a "normal" function. And it will return the filename in exactly the format you require.(It "remembers" all the files you have called the function with previously and calculates a suitable prefix.)  I only used the `.map` mechanic to quickly demonstrate my test cases ...

Comment: Sir , another question , how will makeUnique what exact filename to generate ? how I will based my databased records to the function?

Comment: As I mentioned before `makeUnique()` will keep track of all `fn` arguments it has received in the current seesion of the program. It uses the object `filenames` for this which is kepts in a permanent scope. So, for as long as your nodejs application is running, the filenames are being kept track of and prefixes are calculated accordingly. When you restart your app then `filenames` will start out as an empty object again.

Comment: The problem Sir is that I am tracking record based on the database. I wanted to increment a number to a filename if the filename already exists in the database (based on the records too). for example if I add file with filename DOC it will check if DOC exist since DOC exist on the example below and the latest increment is 1 (DOC-1) then the filename would be DOC-2. If I add DOC again and the latest increment is 2 so the new filename would be DOC-3.

Comment: Tell me Sir , how will I make use of that makeUnique with my sample query above.

Comment: Instead of `getNumberedFileName(fileN)` you use `makeUnique(fileN)`.( OK, admittedly I did not take care of Unix special files like `.rc`, starting with a dot ..)

Answer (score 0):

#suggetion

Your logic could break [ACID](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-acid.html) rules in my view you could try adding an numberOfFiles column instead and use update sql query like
`update set numberOfFiles = numberOfFiles + 1 where yourTable`

Comment: yong , can you explain how this solves the problem ?

Comment: @Mr.MarkTawin isn't it you trying is recording number of files?